# Session variable not found

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

for a long period of time I have an issue with Session variables. I'm looking for some pointers or directions to address this problem. I try to explain what is happening and I understand that the information provided isn't sufficient to understand what is happening, but I'm trying to solve this and it's driving me nuts :-)

I have several Lucee webapplications (Lucee: 5.3.7.48) which are also available as Cordova app. Error messages are sent to my by e-mail. On a daily bases I receive about 100 messages that the session variable can not be found.

[image]
[image]

[APP] is a session variable, set in the file index.cfm.

```
         <cfparam name="SESSION.auth.app" default="">
```

In line 592 there is something like
`<cfif session.auth.app is 1>do something</cfif>`

I don't want to focus on line 592, the real problem is that the session variable is/gets lost. What happens next is that the user is redirect to the login page (login.cfm), because the session is lost and then the problem repeats, it's a kind of loop. The application has a save username/password option.

This all happens when the application is running in the background, like the Cordova app running in the background. I know this because I reached out to a user when receiving 20 error messages, and he told me that I wasn't using the application at the time of the error messages.

In conclusion I measure a user when he is using the login.cfm page. As you van see in the image there is a peak in usage on March 16th, which has to do with the problem described.

[image]

I understand that I provided not much useful information to go on, but can someone give me some directions how to approach this problem?

**UPDATE April 14th**

I have changed the way session vars are set and followed the suggestions in the reactions.

In the application.cfc I have add:

```
<cffunction name="onSessionStart" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" hint="I fire when a new session begins.">
    <cfset SessionRotate()>
    <cfset SESSION.app = ''>
    <cfset SESSION.device = ''>
    <cfset SESSION.app_file_url = 'window.open'>
</cffunction>
```

Restarted Lucee just the be sure. But still the same error messages, APP doesn't exist. After some additional searching I found: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1535-coldfusion-session-is-always-created-even-if-onsessionstart-fails.htm

Could this be a Lucee bug? Are do you have more suggestions to try?

Comment: Where is your `cfparam` line in relation to the line giving the error? Just initialize and set the variable in your Application.cfc file within the `OnSessionStart()` method. Then you know it will always be there. [Lucee documentation](https://docs.lucee.org/guides/cookbooks/application-context-basic.html#onsessionstart)

Comment: Is this happening on random clients only? Are you able to see this happening on a device you can use as a debugging tool and reproduce the issue to see cookie variables, client request headers, server response headers?

Comment: My upvote put your reputation into triple digits.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: @Miguel-F the cfparam is one of the first lines in the index.cfm, way up to line 592. I will check the OnSessionStart, but this is still a strange problem.

Comment: @AndreasRu it is happening with different users on different environments. The user agent is: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36 Edg/89.0.774.75 but also Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_5_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1 and more. The problem is I don't know how to debug, I can't reproduce the problem. I have tried FusionReactor, but that wasn't helpful.

Comment: If the param tag is in index.cfm, acknowledge the possibility that attempts are being made to browse other files in the application without going through the index page first.

Comment: @DanBracuk, can you advice how to use <cfparam name="SESSION.auth.app" default=""> on a different level, like in the application.cfc. Can I add this to the onRequestStart? Thanks for the upvote :-)

Comment: `onRequestStart()` is an effective place to put the `cfparam tag`.  `onSessionStart()` as suggested by @Miguel-F, is equally effective and slightly more efficient in that it will only run once.

Comment: So when using  onSessionStart this should work, right? <cffunction
  name="OnSessionStart"
  access="public"
  returntype="void"
  output="false"
  hint="I fire when a new session begins.">

  <cfif isDefined("url.init") and url.init eq  "reset">
   <cfset onSessionStart()> 
  </cfif>

  <cfparam name="SESSION.auth.app" default="">

 </cffunction> I'm asking because it's generates an error, "key [APP] doesn't exist".

Comment: It might be useful to add a dump of the session scope to the email you are receiving to see if there are any session variables at all.

Comment: No, do not call ` <cfset onSessionStart()>` within the `onSessionStart` method.  you just set your session variable(s) within that method. No `cfparam` either.  Just set the session variable

Answer (score 2):

In your onSessionStart function, Can you please change it to this?

`<cfset session.auth = {}>`

`<cfset session.auth.app = ''>`

I see you are checking `<cfif session.auth.app is 1>do something</cfif>` which should have the **session.auth** defined for it to work.

I hope the above helps.

Also, I'd be interested in knowing what are you dumping on the screen?